# Shell script evaluation failing on windows 10 using cygwin and git bash

Tags: windows, cygwin, git-bash

```
export testval='hdhhdhdh'
echo $testval
if [ ! -d ${testval} ]; then
echo -e "${RED}Please specify jettyScheduler as an environmental 
variable${RESET}"
exit
fi
```

The above evaluation is failing eventhough testval is set explicity in the script .
I got a new laptop with windows 10 OS , the above was working fine using cygwin on Windows 7 . The same is failing using cygwin & git bash on windows 10 . Can someone help ?

Comment: You'll need to provide more information, like what  you expect, what you got, where you're running the script from, &c.

Comment: Hello , the script is run from cygwin on Windows 10 OS . infact it started working when i used                                                                                   
     if [ -z ${testval} ] syntax , what could be the reason for if[! -d ${testval}] to not function properly ? . The expectation with the script in context is that it should not print the echo statement , as it should print the statement only if testval is not set in the environment which is not the case . Let me know if anything additional is required

Answer (score 0):

You've misunderstood what `test -d` does - it checks for existence of a directory, so what you see is expected (assuming that 'hdhhdhdh' isn't the name of a directory).  If you just want to check if an environment is set, then `test -z` (or conversely `test -n`) is one way to do it, as you have seen.

P.S. You should also get into the habit of quoting variables ("$testval") if there's any possibility it may contain spaces.